# Azure Pipelines YAML queue time variable does not expand

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have the following YAML pipeline:

```yaml
stages:
- stage: build
  jobs:
  - job: build
    variables:
    - group: Global
    steps:
    - checkout: self
      persistCredentials: true
      
    - template: build-gitversion.yml@templates
      parameters:
        pushNugetPackages: true
        forcePushNugetPackages: $(forcePushNugetPackages)
        userSteps:
        - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
          displayName: 'dotnet pack'
          inputs:
            command: pack
            packagesToPack: src/xxx/xxx.csproj
            configuration: release
            verbosityPack: Normal
    
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: 'Write-Host $(forcePushNugetPackages)'
```

To be able to set at queue time, if nuget packages should be pushed, I have defined the following variable:

[image]

Here's the definition of the parameter in my template:

```yaml
parameters:
- name: pushNugetPackages
  type: boolean
  default: false
- name: forcePushNugetPackages
  type: string
  default: 'false'
```

The problem is, that the variable `forcePushNugetPackages` is not getting expanded. I tried the following syntaxes:

- `$(forcePushNugetPackages)`
- `${{ variables.forcePushNugetPackages }}`
- `$[variables.forcePushNugetPackages]`

I'm using the value in my template within a condition, which renders to this: `eq('$(forcePushNugetPackages)', True)`.

In the PowerShell task it works as expected:

[image]

Comment: You're getting [variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch) and [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops) mixed up. They are set differently and accessed differently. See the answer by @LoganCodes for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Here's the definition of the parameter in my template:`

I am a little confused, is it a variable and a parameter? To reference parameters, you use the following syntax: `${{ parameters.forcePushNugetPackages }}`. Will referencing it as a parameter suit your needs?

Comment: You guys are right, I kinda mixed up parameters and variables. I thought parameters can only be defined and used in templates. As soon as I created `forcePushNugetPackages` as a parameter in my pipeline it worked like a charm. Thank you guys for guiding me to the solution.